# How to fix "Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported."

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. 
Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

When I try parsing this site doesn't work.

When I Try serialized this pagetext I have a error 
`TypeError: Type 'str' cannot be serialized`

```
from lxml import html

source = 'http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/item.php?type_id=814'
path = '//*[@id="top"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table'

page = requests.get(source)
pagetext = page.text

parser = html.fromstring(pagetext)

result = parser.xpath(path)
print(result)
```

I expect a table Requirements like in site:
http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/item.php?type_id=814

Comment: Why don't you use `element = html.parse(source)` directly? The `html.parse` method supports a URL as you have in the `source` variable as an input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
parser = html.fromstring(bytes(pagetext, encoding='utf8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `parse` function the API provides allows you to directly pass in a URL like you have in your `source` variable:

```
from lxml import html

source = 'http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/item.php?type_id=814'
path = '//*[@id="top"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table'

tree = html.parse(source)

result = tree.xpath(path)

print(result)
```